# How to add timer to app

Tags: android, timer

I am a new android developer. Recently, launched a word puzzle app - <s>[Wozzle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amit.wozzle)</s>

I want to add timer to the game so that a player gets a limited time to make a move. How to do that ? Also, the timer should be displayed to the player.

Comment: @bali182 Profanity is unnecessary, hiding it underneath some asterisks doesn't justify its use either.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to the website

Comment: @Esha Welcome to Stack Overflow! I apologize on behalf of bali182's comment. On the other hand, this site has a wealth of knowledge hidden beneath the surface, and in the future, searching a while will get you the answer you're looking for 98% of the time (I say from personal experience). Also, we generally like questions on this site to be a little more descriptive than this one. If you can include some of your code (but please, keep it brief), then you're that much closer to a great answer. Answering is far easier when the question is specific. Anyway, welcome and good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
public class CountDownTest extends Activity {

    TextView tv; // textview to display the countdown

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        tv = new TextView(this);
        this.setContentView(tv);

        // 5000 is the starting number (in milliseconds)
        // 1000 is the number to count down each time (in milliseconds)
        MyCount counter = new MyCount(5000, 1000);

        counter.start();

    }

    //countdowntimer is an abstract class, so extend it and fill in methods
    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{

        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            tv.setText("done!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv.setText("Left: " + millisUntilFinished/1000);

        }

    }
}
```

Have a look at these links

- [A Stitch in Time](http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html)
- [On screen timer in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248298/on-screen-timer-in-android-application)
- [stop watch logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733867/stop-watch-logic)
- [Android Game Programming: The Game Loop](http://aubykhan.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/android-game-programming-the-game-loop/)